# Jenkins Pipeline Jira Plugin sorted input parameter

Tags: sorting, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira-plugin

My goal is to create a Jenkins Pipeline Input Step where the user can choose from a selection of JIRA versions. I am able to generate the dropdown list of available versions, but would like the order to be reversed.

The current dropdown is as follows:

- REL-3
- REL-2
- REL-1

And my goal is for it to become:

- REL-1
- REL-2
- REL-3

The order of the items makes the dropdown automatically selects REL-3, whereas it should default to REL-1 as it is the earliest version.

I am using the Jenkins [JIRA Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) with the [JiraVersionParameterDefinition](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jira/versionparameter/JiraVersionParameterDefinition.java) to generate the list of versions.

The Jenkins Pipeline code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def jiraVersionForReleaseFromUserInput() {
    releases_list = [
          $class: 'JiraVersionParameterDefinition',
          jiraProjectKey: 'PROJECT_NAME',
          jiraReleasePattern: 'REL-[0-9]+',
          jiraShowRelease: 'false',
          jiraShowArchived: 'false',
    ]
    release = input message: 'Select JIRA Version to release', parameters: [releases_list]
    RELEASE_NAME = release
}
```

My initial thought was the JiraVersionParameterDefinition would have an argument to sort themm but could not fine one. Then I tried using default fields such as `sortReverseOrder`, `sortMode`, and `reverse_order` but they weren't recognized. I have tried to create the list outside the input parameters to be able to sort it beforehand, but it isn't created at that point as when I print it the result is:

```
[$class:JiraVersionParameterDefinition, jiraProjectKey:PROJECT_NAME, jiraReleasePattern:REL-[0-9]+, jiraShowRelease:false, jiraShowArchived:false]
```

Am I missing a sorting parameter that is default on Jenkins Inputs? Is there a way to initialize the list before the input step? Is it possible to add a filter argument that can sort the resulting list?